# how to add new line in div output

Tags: javascript, html

I want an output like this:

```
   1st line-  " Your total purchase cost is Rs.980"
   2nd line-            Thank You!
```

my code snippet:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Your total purchase cost is Rs' +result;
<div id = "result"> </div>
```

I tried adding:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Your total purchase cost is Rs' +result <br> 'Thank You!';
```

and adding a new line with `\n`.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of how to efficiently concatenate multiple strings in javascript? The OP asked how to add new lines in a javascript string so that it renders in the HTML as an actual new line.

Answer (score 2):

If you're injection HTML into some div, new lines should be also done using HTML - `<br />`.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
  'Your total purchase cost is Rs' + result + '<br />Thank You!';
```

Comment: oh!!..this works for me..thanks a lot..!